# Disable caching of #{cache} tag in dev mode

Tags: caching, tags, playframework

I want to disable caching of `#{cache 'myCacheKey', for: '15mn'}` blocks when running in dev mode. I haven't configured memcached so it's just using the JVM heap cache, but I can't find any documentation about disabling this cache.

How can I disable this in dev mode so that changes are reflected immediately?

Comment: Don't know how to disable the cache, but you can build an if clause to check application mode inside a view like this: `#{if play.Play.configuration.get('application.mode') == 'DEV'}`.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own tag for caching that checks for the mode (DEV,PROD) with the code Tom provides in the comments, and use that for caching. Something like:

```
#{if play.Play.configuration.get('application.mode') == 'DEV'}
   #{cache _key, for: _time} 
#{/if}
```

and

```
#{myCache key: 'xxx', time: '15mn'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way is to add Cache.clear() in your test's fixture ( http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/test#aFixturesa )